# Does functions.php apply to every page?

Tags: functions

I am currently trying to add a slider onto my homepage using the Meta Slider plugin but I am also using this code below in my functions.php of my storefront-child theme.

But the slider is being added to every single page that I have and i'm not entirely sure why this is. I haven't added any shortcodes to any of the pages but can't figure out how to only apply it to one page.

This is in my functions.php:

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'child_theme_init' );
function child_theme_init() {
    add_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woa_add_full_slider', 5);
}

function woa_add_full_slider() {
    ?>
    <div id="slider">
        <?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=252 percentwidth=100]"); ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: @TheDeveloper, why don't you make an actual answer from the comment?

Comment: @MarkKaplun weren't sure if my approach was the best solution , but will add a answer now

Comment: Yes, functions.php is the first thing to load of your theme on pretty much every request to your site. It helps establish what to do when when events trigger so you need to cover every case - either in your functions.php or in the templates that get loaded. There are several things happening that you can listen too like 'init' that may have information pertaining to the final page to be loaded or give you options to modify how/what gets chosen. Consider this supplemental to the other answers.

Answer (score 2):

the `if(is_front_page())`  will check if  front page is being viewed, then  load your css and meta slider .

Codex [documention](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page)

```
<?php

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
        # added
        if(is_front_page())
            wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'child_theme_init' );
    function child_theme_init() {
        # added
        if(is_front_page())
        add_action( 'storefront_before_content', 'woa_add_full_slider', 5);
    }

    function woa_add_full_slider() {
        # added
        if(is_front_page()){
        ?>
        <div id="slider">
            <?php echo do_shortcode("[metaslider id=252 percentwidth=100]"); ?>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
```